# Updating a master worksheet that automatically changes other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a central worksheet with all the data in several tables. Let's say I have Table A, B, C, and D, all in one central worksheet.

In the other three worksheets, I have Table B in Worksheet 2, Table C in Worksheet 3, and Table D in Worksheet 4.

What I have tried is to insert a Command Button from the Developers Tab into the master(central) worksheet and then insert this code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sub copyAOne()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newValue As Range
    Set newValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1") = newValue
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: *My question is, in Excel, can I program it so that once I update my central worksheet, Worksheet 2, 3, and 4 change according to my changes in the central worksheet?*  Answer: YES

Comment: Tell me more @Vityata

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What? this doesn't answer my question

Comment: If you read the link and edit your question correspondingly, you would be getting plenty of good answers.

Comment: But it seems like you understood my question...no?

Comment: @JasonBaik Just read the link provided. You're asking a "yes/no" question on whether you **could** automate something. Of course it's possible. However, we don't know what you've tried so far, what your code is and where you got stuck. StackOverflow is not a free coding service and we're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: You might wanna show some of your code just to prove use you at least tried something before asking the question don't you think?... Your question feels like you're just asking for us to code for you.

Comment: Okay. I am a newcomer to Stack, so I didn't know how you guys work here. My bad.

Comment: I made edits after looking at your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something to start you up:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, [tableA]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Test2.xlsm")

    wkb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value

    wkb.Save
    'wkb.Close

End Sub
```

You need the following:

- tableA in the current `Worksheet`
- Test2.xlsm
- You need to put the code in the Worksheet, not in the module.
- Probably it would not work exactly as expected, but the main idea is this one.
- Make sure that you close the "C:\Desktop\Test2.xlsm", before running the file.

Put the code there:
[image]

And in general, if you wanted to do it with a button, and not with an event, this is something you could use:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Test2.xlsm")

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:D16").Copy
    wkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:D16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wkb.Save
    'wkb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: came here to suggest handling the same event as well

Comment: @JasonBayldon - events are a feature that solves plenty of problems :)

Comment: @Vityata Wait, so which part of this code should be personalized?